# Updating Embedded Array And Objects In Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In Mongo I have a collection of post and each post has comments that are embed with a user id, user name and user email.

```
- post
    - comments
           - user_id name email
```

I was wondering how can I update the all the emails that are associated with a certain id?

Comment: for now you can vote on this JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you would have to retrieve comments first, and then update emails.

Depending on which client you use, here is a `mongoid` example:

```rb
comments = post.comments
comments.update_attributes(:email => "a@b.c")
```

Also there is already a *"Use positional operator to update all items in an array"* [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) that, once implemented, will allow you to do it in one shot.

Comment: this feature not scheduled yet ;(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [the $ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), its the only way to update the matching sub(embedded docs) docs.

Comment: it will not work in case if in comments collection will more than one user with same email. It will update first element matched by position.